# Of which class JSon would be in _metadata file when we do a Hive Table Export

Tags: hive

> Export Table employee to /use/path/

The dump created at **/use/path/** contain a file called **_metadata**. The contents of this file are of JSON format

Of which class does the JSon belongs ?

Comment: what you mean by which class?

Comment: the metadata contains information on the table name,columns,column type,data etc